# Creating a control in an async task causes a deadlock

Tags: c#, asynchronous, controls, deadlock, async-await

The expected results would be:

SomeTask
MainAsync
Main

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Main");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    async static Task MainAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => SomeTask());
        Console.WriteLine("MainAsync");
    }

    static async Task SomeTask()
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("SomeTask");
    }
}
```

However, none of the Console.Writeline's are actually called.

The same thing happens even if I write a windows forms app, which does obviously have a win32 message loop.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        await MainAsync();
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    async static Task MainAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => SomeTask());

    static async Task SomeTask()
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

The MessageBox never appears.

Comment: At a guess, creating a control spins up a sync-context, but without an active message-loop; that means it will never get around to processing the message from the sync-context; sync-contexts are ... tricky

Answer (score 1):

Marc is correct; modern Windows Forms controls will establish a WinForms `SynchronizationContext` on their current thread when created.

Thus, `SomeTask` will schedule its continuation onto a Win32 message loop, but there is no thread processing that message loop (e.g., `Application.Run`).

Comment: What about the updated code? It does obviously have a win32 message loop, so why doesn't it work?

Comment: You're still creating the control on *another* (non-UI) thread, which does not have a Win32 message loop.